# MySQL connection issue with error 2003 / 111

Tags: networking, mysql, database, connection, database-administration

I'm running a mysql server using the following command:

```
 mysqld --no-defaults --user=root --port=3310 --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --skip-grant-tables &
```

My understanding is that this command starts up a mysql server daemon as user root that will listen to all interfaces and allows all users to access all databases. Note that I've used --no-defaults, so there is no config file read by mysql.

I'm trying to connect to the server from a different machine using the command:

```
mysql -p -u root -h MYSQL_SERVER_IP --port 3310
```

But I'm getting the following classic error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MYSQL_SERVER_IP' (111)
```

I've switched off all rules using 'iptables -F', both in server and client.
Also the server is ping-able from client and vice-versa.

What am I missing?

Comment: First order of business is to resolve when this is a network or an application issue.  What do you get when, from client, you do `telnet mysql_server_ip 3310`?  Also, `iptables -F` turns off all rules, but not the policies; could we get the output of `iptables -L -n -v` on the server after this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
mysql -p -u root -h MYSQL_SERVER_IP -p 3310
```

isn't correct it should be

```
mysql -p -u root -h MYSQL_SERVER_IP --port 3310
```

without the `--port 3310` the client will try to connect to the default port at `3306`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had originally used --port only, but made a typo when creating the question. Have edited now.